# How do I deploy a web service to a virtual server from the host?

Tags: web-services, visual-studio-2008, sharepoint-2007, windows-server-2003, virtualization

all. First of all I am sorry if this question is better for SuperUser, I couldn't tell. If it is it would be great if someone could migrate it.

So anyway, I'm building this service for SharePoint in Visual Studio 2008 with C#. Of course I need to be able to debug it to build it fast. Unfortunately my OS is XP Pro which can't run SharePoint because it is not a server OS. Instead of reinstalling my OS (which would create other problems) I got Server 2003 + SharePoint Server 2007 up and running inside a virtual machine with Virtual PC. Is there some sort of pipe I can create from Visual Studio that will let me test my service from within the virtual machine?

Thank you!

I guess I should add, these are the tools I have been given. At this time, reinstalling or getting new equipment/software is not an option.

Comment: Maybe if there was some way I could expose the IIS running on the virtual server, I could just modify my Visual Studio project to point to that website.

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely stackoverflow worthy.  It is a development process related question after all.

So you have two issues, deployment and debugging.

For deployment, there are really two ways to approach this.  One is that you create a real .wsp package that you can deploy/install/upgrade via the SharePoint provided mechanisms.  You really should have this prepared since it is the way that your final code should be deployed.  The trouble is that you can only perform the deploy/install/upgrade via a machine connected to the farm.  In this case it would be your VM.  In cases where I have had to work this way, I have scripted the creation of the .wsp and copied it to the server. On the server is another script to do the deployment.  Yes it is more steps than I would like but it does work and it is pretty mindless so it isn't too much of a hassle.

The second approach would be the quicker, less correct way.  In this case if all you are doing is changing the code, then you just need to get your new DLL to replace the old one and bounce IIS.  You might be able to do that all remotely via script fired from Visual Studio after build succeeds action.

As for debugging, you can certainly debug things remotely.  Look into tutorials on remotely debugging processes using Visual Studio.